# NoMethodError at /orders/new undefined method `validate_on_create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, methods, model

I am currently getting a `NoMethodError at /orders/new
undefined method 'validate_on_create' for #<Class:0x000000047fde70>`. My code seems to be simple and should be functional but it is not.

### note

Before this error I got the error `NoMethodError at /orders/new
undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` so I changed `form_for @order` to `form_for Order.new`

Below is my code:

### orders/new

```
<% form_for Order.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :card_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :card_type, [["Visa", "visa"], ["MasterCard", "master"], ["American Express", "american_express"]] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :card_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :card_number %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :card_verification, "Card Verification Value (CVV)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :card_verification %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :card_expires_on %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
    <% end %>
```

### controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
          @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
          @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
          @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
          if @order.save
                  if @order.purchase
                          render :action => "success"
                  else
                          render :action => "failure"
                  end
          else
                  render :action => 'new'
          end
  end
end
```

### model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :card_expires_on, :card_type, :cart_id, :first_name, :ip_address, :last_name
  belongs_to :cart
  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

  validate_on_create :validate_card

  def purchase
          response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
          transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => price_in_cents, :response => response)
          cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
          response.success?
  end

  def price_in_cents
          (cart.total_price*100).round
  end

  private

  def purchase_options
          {
                  :ip => ip_address,
                  :billing_address => {
                    :name     => "",
                    :address1 => "",
                    :city     => "",
                    :state    => "",
                    :country  => "",
                    :zip      => ""
                  }
          }
  end

  def validate_card
          unless credit_card.valid?
                  credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                          errors.add_to_base message
                  end
 end
  end

  def credit_card
          @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
            :type               => card_type,
            :number             => card_number,
            :verification_value => card_verification,
            :month              => card_expires_on.month,
            :year               => card_expires_on.year,
            :first_name         => first_name,
            :last_name          => last_name
          )
  end
end
```

### routes

```
resources :carts
  resources :orders

  get 'cart' => 'carts#show', :as => 'current_cart'
```

### error

```
NoMethodError at /orders/new
undefined method `validate_on_create' for #<Class:0x00000005104ca8>

Order.method_missing
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb, line 55
<class:Order>
app/models/order.rb, line 8
<top (required)>
app/models/order.rb, line 1
block in ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_file
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 469
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.new_constants_in
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 639
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_file
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 468
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.require_or_load
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 353
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_missing_constant
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 502
block in Object.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 192
Object.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 190
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_missing_constant
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 514
block in ActionView.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 192
ActionView.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 190
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_missing_constant
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 514
block in ActionView::CompiledTemplates.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 192
ActionView::CompiledTemplates.const_missing
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb, line 190
#<Class:0x00000004d71be0>#_app_views_orders_new_html_erb___2575536509094394834_41759220
app/views/orders/new.html.erb, line 4
block in ActionView::Template#render
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 145
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 125
ActionView::Template#render
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 143
block (2 levels) in ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render_template
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb, line 47
block in ActionView::TemplateRenderer#instrument
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb, line 38
block in ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 123
ActiveSupport::Notifications::Instrumenter#instrument
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb, line 20
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 123
ActionView::TemplateRenderer#instrument
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb, line 38
block in ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render_template
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb, line 46
```

Any insight is fully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**validate_on_create** has been removed after rails 2.0.3 refer [api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.0.3/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate_on_create).

Use `validate :method_name, :on => :create`

so for your case following should work

```
validate :validate_card, :on => :create
```